# Is there a Hausdorff space having a countably infinite topology? And what happens if we weaken the Hausdorff condition?

Tags: general-topology

I was looking at R.H. Bing's 1948 example of a connected [countable Hausdorff space](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1953-004-03/S0002-9939-1953-0060806-9/S0002-9939-1953-0060806-9.pdf), and it made me wonder if we can find a Hausdorff space having a countably infinite topology. It appears the answer is negative. Is my argument below correct, or is there a clever example I am not aware of?

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space with an infinite topology. Then $X$ is infinite, and there cannot be two points all of whose neighborhoods have finite complements.  Indeed, if this happens, the
two points could not have disjoint neighborhoods, violating the Hausdorff condition.

Now, select a point $p_{1}$ of $X$ with an open neighborhood $U_{1}$ whose complement is infinite. Notice that $X-U_{1}$ is also an infinite Hausdorff space, and the same reasoning applies to it. That is, there is $p_{2}$ in $X-U_{1}$ with an open neighborhood $U_{2}$ contained in $X-U_{1}$ and whose complement $(X-U_{1})-U_{2}$ is infinite. Carrying this process *ad infinitum* produces a family of disjoint neighborhoods $\{U_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Then, for each subset $A$ of the natural numbers, the set $U_{A}=\bigcup_{n\in A}U_{n}$ is open in $X$ and contains $x_{n}$ if and only if $n\in A$. Hence, we have constructed a family $\{U_{A}:A\mbox{ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$}\}$ of open sets of $X$ having cardinality
$2^{\aleph_{0}}$.

As for what happens if we weaken the Hausdorff condition, the answer is positive. For example, the natural numbers with the finite complement topology is a [$T_{1}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space) space with a countably infinite topology. Furthermore, if we let $O(X)$ denote the number of open sets of a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$, it is well known that for any [$T_{0}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_space) space $|X|\leq O(X)\leq 2^{|X|}$. Indeed, on one hand $O(X)\leq 2^{|X|}$ is clear. On the other, we can define a map $f:X\rightarrow\mathcal{T}$ by $f(p)=X-\mbox{closure}(\{p\})$. The $T_0$ condition implies this map is one-to-one, for if two points have the same image under $f$, their closures will be the same and thus, every open set containing one point must contain the other as well, violating the $T_{0}$ condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any infinite Hausdorff space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ contains a countably infinite discrete subspace $D$ (classic standard fact, proved many times on this site even. (Indeed also a pairwise disjoint countable family of open sets (the argument you gave goes in the right direction but needs more precision), but we don't need that even).

For every $A \subseteq D$  we can find an $O_A \in \mathcal{T}$ so that $O_A \cap D=A$, as all subsets are open in $D$. It follows that $A \to O_A$ is an  injection from $\mathscr{P}(D)$ into $\mathcal{T}$ so that $|\mathcal{T}| \ge \mathfrak{c}$.